# Replace String in File with 1st,2nd... line in another file

Tags: string, replace, awk, sed, line

I have a string in file1 stored as a variable.
I need to replace the variable in file1 with the first line of another file - file2.
stop for a while(15 seconds or so) So that i use file1 for some 
Then replace the variable in file1 with with the second line of file2.
stop for a while(15 seconds or so)
Repeat the above step for the third line of file2 and so on. And exit after doing the replacement with the last row in file2.

Comment: I am using the below statement to replace the variable in mysqlcreatedb.sh with the contents of file get_dbacct_name.output Can anyone please make it replace the variable with the first line of get_dbacct_name.output and then the second line and so on with a gap of say 15 seconds between every row.
sed -i "s/$var1/$(sed 's:/:\\/:g' get_dbacct_name.output)/" mysqlcreatedb.sh

Comment: Why are you using the comment to show details instead of the question main area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  # Using sed is not a good idea if file2 may contain characters that have
  # meaning in a sed regex (or may be your delimiter), and substituting it
  # directly into the awk code would break if there was a quote in there.
  # This should work with everything.
  #
  # Also, we'll need the template file later, so we can't replace in-place.
  # Instead, write the result of the substitution to its own file and work
  # on that.
  awk -v SUBST="$line" '{ gsub("VARIABLE", SUBST, $0); print $0 }' file1 > file1.cooked

  # Instead of sleeping, I encourage you to do the actual work here. That
  # way, you will not introduce brittle timing issues that will vex you when
  # things break in non-obvious ways.
  sleep 15
done < file2
```